# How to update value of custom customer attribute (image) from frontend in magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, image

Trying to update custom customer attribute value while customer edit from frontend , and my field is file upload control but unable to save the attribute

Tried

```
$customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
$customer->setCustomAttribute('profileimage', '123.jpg');
$this->customerRepository->save($customer);
```

but getting error Call to a member function setCustomAttribute() on null

secondly, I have also try

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$customer = $observer->getCustomerDataObject();
$customerId = $customer->getId();
$customerData = $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('profileimage', '123.jpg');
$customer->updateData($customerData);
$customerResource = $this->customerFactory->create();
$customerResource->saveAttribute($customer, 'profileimage');
```

Still getting error for updateData() function not found.

can anyone help me out to save custom customer attribute from frontend for image in Magento 2.

Comment: How you create the attribute? Share that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below.

```
protected $customer;

protected $customerFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer
    \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
)
{
    $this->customer = $customer;
    $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
}

$customerId = "1";
$customer = $this->customer->load($customerId);
$data = "customer attribute value";
$customerData = $customer->getDataModel();
$customerData->setCustomAttribute('customer_attribute_code',$data);
$customer->updateData($customerData);
$customerResource = $this->customerFactory->create();
$customerResource->saveAttribute($customer, 'customer_attribute_code');
```

It will work fine. Please check and let me know still you got the error.

Also, you can [download](https://github.com/kishan-cybercom/sk-profile-picture) extension which is already developed.

Thanks

Comment: Tried above code but unfortunately it doesn't work for me

Comment: Tried above code but unfortunately it doesn't work for me , the custom attribute which i have created is of type 'file' and whatever solutions i have got works for input type 'text' not for 'file'.  my custom field is $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'profileimage',
            [
                'type'         => 'text',
                'label'        => 'Profile Picture',
                'input'        => 'file',                         not working for this.

Comment: while trying to update attribute of type 'file' i'm getting below error        Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException: Cannot gather stats! Warning!stat(): stat failed for C:/xampp741/htdocs/mag240s/pub/media/customer/123.jpg in C:\xampp741\htdocs\mag240s\vendor\magento\framework\Filesystem\Driver\File.php:77